# Unknown attributes in base class

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am looking at creating a class that has a set attribute function that can store an attribute into the database. The problem is I don't know what type of attribute people will want to store, I just know that they just want to store different attributes based on user input.

Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is possible?

Comment: So, a key/value storage?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you want to query for the values or not.

If you don't want to search for the values, you can always `pickle` the data and store it in a `BLOB`.

If you want to search (efficiently) for keys and values you have to have as many columns as you have different types and perhaps add a "type" column which tells you which column to use.